# SSRS integration with ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I am working on SSRS 2010 and able to integrate with ASP.net 2013. My problem is the file share link which works fine on report server doesn't work on Report viewer on ASP.net application. Here is my code.

```
       ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
       ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri "http://ServerName//reportserver");
       ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Report2";
       ReportViewer1.SizeToReportContent = true;
       ReportViewer1.HyperlinkTarget = "_blank";
       ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: is SSRS and ASP.NET on the same box?

Comment: No, they are on separate boxes

Comment: The report server url in the above is localhost.  I'm assuming that is wrong then?

Comment: Sorry, just not expose the box name!

Comment: Actually the report is rendered correctly. but when I click the link for the file share, it opens blank page. In report server it opens the file found in that particular shared folder .